# C++ design suggestions

Tags: java, c++

I made a program in `Java` a while back that is essentially a math quiz, it randomly generates simple math problems based on user input. Now, I'm teaching myself `C++` and I was just wondering, based on efficiency and organization, what is the best way to convert this program. For example should my methods be classes, should they stay in one class, ect. Any help on this would be much appreciated! This is my current `Java` code

```
public class MathQuiz {
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

int numberOne;
int numberTwo;
int actualSolution;
int userSolution;
int numberOfQuestions;
int counter = 1;
int temp;
int randomOperation;
int totalCorrect;
int totalIncorrect;
long startTime;
long endTime;
long totalTime;
double percent;
String operation;
String done;

public void mathQuizzer(){
    System.out.println("Welcome to Math Quiz!");
    System.out.println("What kind of questions would you like to answer?");
    System.out.println("Enter + for Addition");
    System.out.println("Enter - for Subtraction");
    System.out.println("Enter * for Multiplication");
    System.out.println("Enter / for Division");
    System.out.println("Enter m for Mix");
    operation = s.next();
    System.out.println("How many questions would you like to answer? ");
    numberOfQuestions = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(counter <= numberOfQuestions){

        if(operation.equals("+")){
            System.out.println("Question " + counter + ":");
            createAdditionEquation();
            checkSolution();
            counter++;
        }
        else if(operation.equals("-")){
            System.out.println("Question " + counter + ":");
            createSubtractionEquation();
            checkSolution();
            counter++;
        }
        else if(operation.equals("*")){
            System.out.println("Question " + counter + ":");
            createMultiplicationEquation();
            checkSolution();
            counter++;
        }
        else if(operation.equals("/")){
            System.out.println("Question " + counter + ":");
            createDivisionEquation();
            checkSolution();
            counter++;
        }
        else if (operation.equals("m")){
            System.out.println("Question " + counter + ":");
            createMixEquation();
            checkSolution();
            counter++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Sorry invalid operation");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    report();
}

public void createAdditionEquation(){
    numberOne = (int)(Math.random() * (100 + 1));
    numberTwo = (int)(Math.random() * (100 + 1));
    actualSolution = numberOne + numberTwo;

    System.out.println(numberOne + " + " + numberTwo + "= ?");
}

public void createSubtractionEquation(){
    numberOne = (int)(Math.random() * (100 + 1));
    numberTwo = (int)(Math.random() * (100 + 1));
    if(numberOne >= numberTwo){
        actualSolution = numberOne - numberTwo;
    }
    else{
        numberOne = temp;
        numberOne = numberTwo;
        numberTwo = temp;
        actualSolution = numberOne - numberTwo;
    }

    System.out.println(numberOne + " - " + numberTwo + "= ?");
}

public void createMultiplicationEquation(){
    numberOne = (int)(Math.random() * (10 + 1));
    numberTwo = (int)(Math.random() * ((20 - 1) + 1));
    actualSolution = numberOne * numberTwo;

    System.out.println(numberOne + " * " + numberTwo + "= ?");
}

public void createDivisionEquation(){
    numberOne = (int)(Math.random() * (100 + 1));
    numberTwo = (int)(1 +(Math.random() * (10 - 1)));

    if((numberOne >= numberTwo) && (numberOne%numberTwo == 0)){
        System.out.println(numberOne + " / " + numberTwo + "= ?");
        actualSolution = numberOne / numberTwo;
    }
    else{
        createDivisionEquation();
    }
}

public void createMixEquation(){
    randomOperation = (int)(Math.random() * (5 - 1));
    System.out.println("Random Operation: " + randomOperation);
    if(randomOperation == 0){
        createAdditionEquation();
    }
    else if(randomOperation == 1){
        createSubtractionEquation();
    }
    else if(randomOperation == 2){
        createMultiplicationEquation();
    }
    else
        createDivisionEquation();
}

public void checkSolution(){

    System.out.println("Answer = ");
    userSolution = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    if(userSolution == actualSolution){
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        System.out.println("#########################");
        System.out.println();
        totalCorrect++;
    }
    else if(userSolution != actualSolution){
        System.out.println("Sorry, wrong answer. The correct solution is: " + actualSolution);
        System.out.println("#########################");
        System.out.println();
        totalIncorrect++;
    }

}

public void report(){
    percent = ((double) totalCorrect / numberOfQuestions) * 100;
    totalTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
    System.out.println("Report:");
    System.out.println("Questions Answered: " + numberOfQuestions);
    System.out.println("Total Correct: " + totalCorrect);
    System.out.println("Total Incorrect: " + totalIncorrect);
    System.out.println("Percent: " + percent + "%");
    System.out.println("Time taken: " + totalTime + " seconds");
}

}
```

It should be noted that I know this program isn't optimized, and I'm okay with that for the time being

Comment: Java and C++ are both object-oriented.  If you're only using one class for Java, I don't see why you would use multiple classes for a C++ version of the same code.  That isn't to say that for this specific instance a single class is the most efficient way of doing this (in either language), just that I don't see why you'd split it into different classes in C++ if you haven't done so in another OOP language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about program design. Without going into the merits of your current program (check out [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that), a good OO design is a good design and a bad one a bad one, irrespective of language.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it as close to Java. It uses simple means, which can 1:1 be translated into C++.
To change the design, that can be done afterwards, especially if you are relatively new to C++.

There are no technique shifts like Java generics / C++ templating.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my original comment as well as answers others have posted here...

If you're trying to teach yourself C++, and you already know Java, well the two are pretty similiar.  So teach yourself C++ based on what you already know about Java.

You know how to handle IO in Java.  Look up some documentation and start practicing IO with C++, it's a little different.

You know how to handle methods in Java, compare that to C++ (they're virtually the same).

But on the flip side, if you want to concern yourself with efficiency, orginazation, or optimization, you should probably start by doing that with whatever language you know best.  As it stands, or at least in the way you phrased your question, you seem to be trying to accomplish both of those goals in a single bound, when it'd be far better to choose one or the other and focus on that.  If you simply copy & pasted your code over and fixed the syntax difference between Java and C++, the C++ version of the code would essentially be exactly as orginized, efficient, and optimized as the Java version of your code.